# Run time error on Do Loop in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, replace, find, overflow

I just wrote a VBA script to perform a bulk find and replace in Excel.  I need to perform this function for over 150,000 cells worth of data.  I use a Do Loop to compare the value on Sheet A with the values (FIND) and related codes (REPLACE) on Sheet B.

I am using an index counter declared as Dim i as Integer, with a Do Loop controlling each iteration of the index.  The VBA script works, but I receive a "Run-Time error '6':  Overflow" error message once the index crosses 30,000?  Is there a limit to how many times you can iterate a Do Loop, or does anyone know of a good way to perform a bulk find and replace in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace(oldValue,NewValue,xlPart)

ActiveSheet.Cells contains all cells within the sheet.

Hope this helps

Comment: I should have been more clear.  There is some logic behind the replace.  Sheet A contains 150,000 rows of data, with one of the columns being an alphanumeric code.  Sheet B contains the list that translates those codes into something more meaningful.  I wrote a macro that takes each row on Sheet A, finds the translation code on Sheet B and then swaps it out.  There are 250 code possibilities or else I would do a simple nested If formula.